# Why dummy Write in I2C Read operation?

Tags: i2c, eeprom

Why do you need to write nothing to an I2C component before reading from it?  In a AT24C128C, for example:

> A Random Read requires a dummy byte write sequence to load in the data word address.

I am not getting why there is dummy write in read operation.

Comment: There is no fundamental requirement for a dummy write when reading from a I2C device. But maybe some particular device needs it. What device are you asking about? Please give a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Could you be thinking of SPI? In this case, when reading, the master must continue generating clocks which (normally) requires a write operation (data is ignored by the slave).

Comment: Huh?  *What* dummy write?  I have no idea what you are talking about, as there is nothing customarily called a "dummy write" relating to IIC.  Without a specific example, this mess needs to be closed.

Comment: for AT24C128C i am asking.

Comment: @ABSTONE: Please add specific information to your question (aka edit it) not only a part number. It is not very polite to let us all search for the datatsheet and browse it from start to end. Otherwise this question is going to stay closed.

Answer (score 6):

An I2C transaction is either (all) read or (all) write. Hence for an I2C slave device that has more than 1 register and that wants to support individual reading of those registers, there must be a mechanism to specify the address of the register that is read. But this can't be done in the read transaction, because all data flow in a read transaction is from slave to master.

The way out of this dilemma is to define that the first (data) word(s) in a write transaction define the address of the affected register, both for writing *and for reading*. Hence to read register N, you first do a write to register N, but you don't write anything: the (write) transaction consists of just the address N. But the device remembers N, and when you do a subsequent read, the device will provide the data at address N.

So the write is not realy a dummy (non-functional) transaction: it sets the read address.